# Offset top behaving weird in jquery2 and jquery3

Tags: jquery, html

In first demo I'm using `jquery 2.1.1` and getting offset top of `a` tag `22` in chrome, and its remains same while scrolling,

but when I'm using `jquery 3.1.1` offset changes while scrolling.

**Demo 1 with `jquery 2.1.1`**

```js
console.log($('a').offset().top);
$(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log($('a').offset().top);
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
}
a {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">hidden anchor</a>
```

**Demo 2 with `jquery 3.1.1`**

```js
console.log($('a').offset().top);
$(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log($('a').offset().top);
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
}
a {
  font-size: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">hidden anchor</a>
```

Why this is happening.

Comment: there was some breaking changes to `offset`: https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#offset

Comment: Broken in 2.1.1; working in 3.1.1 - When you scroll down, it makes sense for the offset of a single element to change. Think of the top of the window as 0. Anything below this line is `+`, and anything above is `-`. As the element goes up (you scroll down), the offset decreases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery offset().top returns wrong value - error with margin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277608/jquery-offset-top-returns-wrong-value-error-with-margin)

Comment: @J.Titus, I don't think that's correct: `offset()` is supposed to return the position relative to the document; what you're describing would be relative to the viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery 2 has the correct behavior; `offset()` is relative to the document, so scroll position should not change it.

Note the emphasized bit here:

> When using the .offset() method, the first item in the jQuery collection must be a DOM element that has a DOM getBoundingClientRect() method. (All browsers supported by jQuery 3.0 have this API.) Any other input may result in jQuery throwing an error. **Also note that the element must be visible** and currently in a document (i.e., not disconnected). https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#offset

When the element is visible, you get correct behavior in jQuery 3 (the `offset()` remains the same regardless of scroll position) but when the element is hidden using `font-size:0`, then `offset()` incorrectly returns a viewport-relative value (as far as I can tell, it's passing through the viewport-relative `getBoundingClientRect()` value for hidden elements. I don't know why it would do that, but the numbers match up).

```js
console.log($('a.visible').offset().top);
console.log($('a.visible')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
console.log($('a.hidden').offset().top);
console.log($('a.hidden')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
$(window).scroll(function() {
   console.log($('a.visible').offset().top);
   console.log($('a.visible')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
   console.log($('a.hidden').offset().top);
   console.log($('a.hidden')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
}

a.hidden {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="visible" href="#">Not-hidden anchor</a>
<a class="hidden" href="#">hidden anchor</a>
```

The best workaround would seem to be to not try to test the position of a hidden element; use some container element with a real document position instead.

Answer (score 1):

As many have pointed out, it's due to changes in the way `offset` works with hidden elements. I've dug through the code, and came across the piece of code that is (was) responsible for that behaviour:

```
rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Make sure element is not hidden (display: none)
    if ( rect.width || rect.height ) { //this line is responsible
        doc = elem.ownerDocument;
        win = getWindow( doc );
        docElem = doc.documentElement;

        return {
            top: rect.top + win.pageYOffset - docElem.clientTop,
            left: rect.left + win.pageXOffset - docElem.clientLeft
        };
    }

    // Return zeros for disconnected and hidden elements (gh-2310)
    return rect;
```

The relevant line is `if (rect.width || rect.height)` which means, if the element has no height or width, it skips that part and returns the relative position.

However, it seems this has been [fixed in the current code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js#L93), so it should work with newer releases again. Now jQuery doesn't check for the width or height of `getBoundingClientRect()`, but for results of `getClientRects()`.

```
if ( !elem.getClientRects().length ) {
  return { top: 0, left: 0 };
}
```

When having a text hidden with `font-size:0`, `getClientRects()` returns an array with some values, whereas the result of a really hidden element (`display:none`) returns an empty array, so the newer condition will work for "soft"(?)-hidden elements again.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('hidden').getClientRects());

console.log(document.getElementById('removed').getClientRects());
```

```css
#hidden{
  font-size:0;
 }
#removed{
   display:none;  
}
```

```html
<div id="hidden">I'm hidden.</div>
<div id="removed">I'm display:none</div>
```